# How to use an index match function in an array with duplicate values

Tags: indexing, excel-formula, duplicates, match

I have a set of data that outlines soil composition in the following manner:

[spreadhsheet screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EwSFk.jpg)

with substrate types listed in the header, and percentages from 0-100 for each type listed in the rows below.

In column FP I have the following formula:

```
    =IFERROR(IF(AND((INDEX($FF$1:$FO$1,MATCH(LARGE(FF3:FO3,1),FF3:FO3,0)))="",IF((LARGE(FF3:FO3,1))=100,"",INDEX($FF$1:$FO$1,MATCH(LARGE(FF3:FO3,2),FF3:FO3,0)))=""),"",IF(OR((INDEX($FF$1:$FO$1,MATCH(LARGE(FF3:FO3,1),FF3:FO3,0)))="",(IF((LARGE(FF3:FO3,1))=100,"",INDEX($FF$1:$FO$1,MATCH(LARGE(FF3:FO3,2),FF3:FO3,0))))=""),CONCAT("The shoreline substrate is primarily composed of ",(INDEX($FF$1:$FO$1,MATCH(LARGE(FF3:FO3,1),FF3:FO3,0))),(IF((LARGE(FF3:FO3,1))=100,"",INDEX($FF$1:$FO$1,MATCH(LARGE(FF3:FO3,2),FF3:FO3,0)))),". "),CONCAT("The shoreline substrate is primarily composed of ",(INDEX($FF$1:$FO$1,MATCH(LARGE(FF3:FO3,1),FF3:FO3,0)))," and ",(IF((LARGE(FF3:FO3,1))=100,"",INDEX($FF$1:$FO$1,MATCH(LARGE(FF3:FO3,2),FF3:FO3,0)))),". "))),"")
```

This is meant to generate a sentence that reads "The shoreline substrate is primarily composed of [most common substrate type]**, and [second most common substrate type]**."

*(with the bold section appearing only if there are at least two types of substrate present).

The formula works perfectly, except for instances where the percentages of the two most common substrates are the same as can be seen in FP2, where the sentence reads "The shoreline substrate is primarily composed of sand, and sand" instead of sand and gravel.

Any ides on how to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use AGGREGATE to help choose the next column that matches:

```
 ="The shoreline substrate is primarily composed of " &INDEX($1:$1,AGGREGATE(15,6,COLUMN(FF2:FO2)/(FF2:FO2=LARGE(FF2:FO2,1)),1)) & IF(LARGE(FF2:FO2,1)<> 100," and " & INDEX($1:$1,AGGREGATE(15,6,COLUMN(FF2:FO2)/(FF2:FO2=LARGE(FF2:FO2,2)),COUNTIF(FF2:FO2,LARGE(FF2:FO2,1)))),"")
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you! This works perfectly. Admittedly I have no idea how it works, but it's great.

Comment: Learn the Aggregate function, it is very powerful.  Could be better but is still one of my main goto functions.